# Ionic | Android: Files in /res/raw not found. Removed in release bundle

Tags: android, build, release, ionic6

The bundle in `release` does not generate the `res/raw` folder. Therefore, libraries like PushNotification that read the sound from that folder do not work correctly.

I need the `audio.mp3` file to exist in the release bundle inside the `res/raw` folder

The problem only exists in the `release bundle`. In the `debug bundle` it works correctly.

I show how the folder structure is inside the `apk` in a bundle made with `debug`. Notice how the `audio.mp3` file exists.

```bash
.
└── apk
    ├── assets
    │   └── ...
    ...
    ...
    │   └──  ...
    └── res
        ├── color
        ├── color-night-v8
        ├── color-v21
        ├── color-v23
        └── color-v31
        └── raw
            ├──  audio.mp3
```

Now I show how is the folder structure inside the apk in a bundle made with release. See how the raw folder does not exist

```bash
.
└── apk
    ├── assets
    │   └── ...
    ...
    ...
    │   └──  ...
    └── res
        ├── color
        ├── color-night-v8
        ├── color-v21
        ├── color-v23
        └── color-v31
```

This means that the push notification will not sound with the custom audio.

### Replication

Here I present a repository with a simple project of an ionic app that reproduces the mentioned error.

https://github.com/WilmerRS/ionic-push-notification-raw-files

Build, create apk as release and review the generated apk.

### Aditional Context

This is the configuration tried so that the audio.mp3 file is not removed from the bundle in release. It has not achieved any effect.

Keep file, `android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources tools:keep="@raw/audio.mp3, @raw/audio, @raw/*"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
</resources>
```

Proguard rules `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`

```bash
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {public static <fields>;} 
-keep class **.R$*
```

Ionic config.xml `./config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   ...
   <platform name="android">
      ...
      <resource-file src="resources/audio.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/audio.mp3" />
      ...
   </platform>
</widget>
```